# Why regularexpressionvalidator is being ignored?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, webforms

I have implemented a regex using regularexpressionvalidator but it doesn't work.

It's like that it's ignoring the validator. Why ?

```
  <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                New Password
                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtnewPassword"
                                     ErrorMessage="*" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" ValidationGroup="acc"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexValNewPassword" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" ValidationGroup="acc"
                                    ControlToValidate="txtnewPassword"
                                    EnableClientScript="False"
                                    ErrorMessage="***"
                                    ValidationExpression="^[1-9]+[0-9]*$" Visible="True">
                                    *
                                </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

                            </label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtnewPassword" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control passwords"></asp:TextBox>

                        </div>
```

Update:

See.. I want my regex to throw an error when I only input a string of digits e.g. 123455. It should only accept mixed chars string e.g. 12ac3b12 or aac2211@11

Comment: If I am not wrong then this can be simplified as ^[1-9][0-9]*$

Comment: not working bro

Comment: May I get your input string that you are trying to match?

Comment: 123aaa. Is my input string

Comment: This won't match even with your regex given in your post. May I know what are you trying to match? Give some samples that should match and some that don't match?

Comment: With your regex ^[1-9]+[0-9]*$ it will match only digits one or more not starting with a zero.

Comment: See.. I want my regex to throw error when I only input a string of digits e.g. 123455. It should only accept mixed chars string e.g. 12ac3b12 or aac2211@11

Comment: So you want the input should be accepted only if it contains at least 1 alphabet and at least one digit? You should update your question and clearly mention constraints for your valid password.

Comment: yes, I did .. chec

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead to check if there are not only digits and 2 positive lookaheads to check there is at least 1 character from the character class and at least 1 digit. `^(?!\d+$)(?=.*[a-z@])(?=.*\d)[@a-z\d]+$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/azCYOQ/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird it works but when i begin with capital characters i.e. A, B etc then it doesn't work

Comment: You can add to the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) what you want to match `^(?=.*[A-Za-z@])(?=.*\d)[@a-zA-Z\d]+$` (This part `(?!\d+$)` Can actually be removed from my previous example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex that will not match if the input is only digits. It will only match if the input has at least one digit and one alphabet, as per your current requirements. Here minimum password length is 2 and you can make it any length by specifying number here {N,} You can further tweak the regex in case you have similar other requirements regarding character set or let me know and I can further update the regex.

```
^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d).{2,}$
```

Demo,

https://regex101.com/r/Fv7cw7/1

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `^[1-9]+[0-9]*$` matches only digits and should start with 1-9.

To check if there is at least a character and a digit you could use a positive lookahead.

`^(?=.*[A-Za-z@])(?=.*\d)[@a-zA-Z\d]+$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bt9c4G/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z@])` Positive lookahead to assert 1 character from the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)
- `(?=.*\d)` Positive lookahead to assert 1 digit
- `[@a-zA-Z\d]+` Match 1+ times what is allowed in the character class. You can add to the character class what you would allow to match.
- `$` End of the string

Due to the 2 positive lookaheads, the minimum length is 2 characters. If you want to match a minimum length like for example 8, you can add a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) like `{8}` to the character class instead of a `+`.